# Laravel - Best practice to check if files are converted

Tags: laravel, queue, task, jobs

Currently I am trying to figure out what is the best practice to convert and monitor files conversions to another extension.

The general idea is that a monitoring service will be running and check every minut or so if there are any new files in the directory and convert them to another extension.

**Jobs**

My first idea was create a new queued job for every document that was written to the directory execute the job that handles that specific conversion and mark it as complete.

The upside to this is can monitor correctly if any conversion fails and report it back. However the downfall is that a mass conversion of allot of documents (1000+) will take much longer then running the conversion once for all those documents

**Tasks**

The other idea I am having is to add a task within laravel and monitor every minute what documents are converted and what are not, this allows me to bulk conversion everything and have a fast conversion.

However the downside is I must write my own logging instead of using somthing like supervisor.

What do you guys think is the best practice for this with in mind that I want full logging of everything converted and still maintain the fastest possible conversion rate.

Comment: I think for the `fastest possible conversion rate` you should not use php/laravel. For example in Java you can create a `WatchService` that notifies you instantly if a file is created/modified/deleted. Your java program could connect to the same database like your laravel page to share some data like what files were converted or the amount of time it took

Comment: Do you know how many documents you recieve beforehand? Can this be a single one? Or is this always a few / a lot? You could consider introducing two types of jobs; `ConvertFileJob` and `ConvertBatchFilesJob`. That way you don't have to start a single job for a whole bunch of documents, instead they run in a single one.

Comment: Problem is I do not know up front how many documents there, but there are always more then one :-). But the are not always present at the same time... (Give or take 5 minutes for all the documents to get in the directory)